# How to parse the returned JSON and assign it some properties on an object in VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

In a VB.Net application (v4.0 of the .Net Framework) I am making a call to an API that returns the following:

```
{"CFResponse":{"AccountDetails":[{"AccountNum":"TEST","CurrentBalance":-58.24,"OriginalBalance":1530.01,"TotalPaid":215.33}]}}
```

I also have a variable (`userInfo`) holding an instance of `GetUserInfoResult.vb` that has a bunch of set properties from previous logic.

What is a clean way of getting the JSON data mapped to properties on my instance?

`CurrentBalance` > `userInfo.Balances.CurrentBalance`

`OriginalBalance` > `userInfo.Balances.OriginalBalance`

`TotalPaid` > `userInfo.Balances.TotalPaid`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON in Visual basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079177/deserializing-json-in-visual-basic)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize) or [this maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406948/deserialize-json-into-an-object-vb-net) or if you don't mind converting then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net?rq=1)

Comment: @AFriend If I were to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of GetUserInfoResult)(jsonString)` would I not lose the other properties already set? Or are you saying I should create a `Dto` class that maps exactly to the JSON structure? But if I do that, it seems tedious, cause the returned JSON is quite messy when I only need them three properties!

Comment: Well you can Deserialise to a temporary object, set the 3 properties you need, and then get rid of the temporary one. Also, as long as the property names match, you shouldn't need the JSON attributes to deserialise properly

Comment: hmm, can you show me how please in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make some changes but the rough idea is here

```
Private Sub SomeJsonThing()
    Dim json = "{'cFResponse': {'AccountDetails':[{'AccountNum':'TEST','CurrentBalance':-58.24,'OriginalBalance':1530.01,'TotalPaid':215.33}]}}"

    Dim tmpJObject As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)
    Dim cfResponse As JToken = tmpJObject("CFResponse")
    Dim accDetails As JToken = cfResponse("AccountDetails")

    Dim accountDetailsList = accDetails.ToObject(Of List(Of AccountDetails))
    Dim accInfo = accountDetailsList.First

    userInfo.Balances.CurrentBalance = accInfo.CurrentBalance
    userInfo.Balances.OriginalBalance = accInfo.OriginalBalance
    userInfo.Balances.TotalPaid = accInfo.TotalPaid
End Sub

Public Class AccountDetails
    Property AccountNum As String
    Property CurrentBalance As Double
    Property OriginalBalance As Double
    Property TotalPaid As Double
End Class
```

I'd separate the JSON reading into a different method, and the setting of the properties as well.

Comment: Am I right that I first need to do `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 10.0.3`?

Comment: Whichever compatible version, yes. If you prefer not to install the package then [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize) I provided has a `JavascriptSerializer` method